# Localstorage clears automatically in ios 8.1

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html, cordova

The items stored in the localStorage of my phonegap application cleared one day suddenly. The issue happens in iOS 8.1 version.

Is there any expiration date for localStorage?
Will the iOS clear localStorage of apps automatically?

It occurs multiple times a day for the last 1 week.

Any quick help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: None of my apps with localStorage show this behaviour. If you use sessionStorage instead localStorage this can happen. Do you use any library for using localStorage?

Comment: I am using inbuilt localStorage of browser, no additional library used

Comment: Any idea how often this happens?? I hope this happens only when ios is low on memory..

Answer (score 1):

When iOS gets low on storage space it will "clean" your app and remove everything in localStorage